# Firebase Crashlytics DSYM file

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, crashlytics

I'm trying to integrate Crashlytics in my app and in the 5. step it says:

Xcode versions 10 or higher only: Add your app’s dSYM location as an input file that enables Crashlytics to automatically generate dSYMs for large apps more quickly. For example:

`${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}/Contents/Resources/DWARF/${TARGET_NAME}`

I copy/pasted this path to my Input Files and also this one `$(SRCROOT)/$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)`

Debug Info is set to DWARF with dSYM file.

Should `${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}/Contents/Resources/DWARF/${TARGET_NAME}` be like this or this is a dynamic path and I need to replace it with my current DSYM file path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using that path should work, but if you run into issues you can manually specify the path as well, or follow these instructions if it's still not working https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports-new-sdk?authuser=0&platform=ios#upload-dsyms.

Comment: Do I need to do this manually for every missing DSYM or just once ?

Comment: Just once, as long as you're using the recommended path in your run script ${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}/Contents/Resources/DWARF/${TARGET_NAME}