# Firebase crashlytics upload dsym automatically

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, crashlytics

I'm using React Native Firebase. At firebase crashlytics I have missing DSYM's.
[image]

What's the right way to add dSYMs automatically on every build? I guess it should be added to run script? If so, how can I get the path to `/path/to/pods/directory/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols` and `/path/to/dSYMs`.

Thanks!

Comment: same problem I am facing, @Iecham have you find the correct script which will work everytime whenever i make a release build for providng QA or client for testing?
Note: I do not wan app store solution, my app is not published yet.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to do it automatically, But here is what I'm doing right now https://gist.github.com/medyo/43a76da1c4cc5aae0eaaa1a16bb9ae97

Answer (score 7):

This question has been answered in [previous posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61068511/firebase-crashlytics-dsym-file/61083389#61083389), but I'll provide a quick summary. The paths below will automatically find your dSYMs and upload them.

Here is what goes into your runscript:

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"
```

This is what goes into your input file:

```
${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}/Contents/Resources/DWARF/${TARGET_NAME}
```

You can use this terminal command to find the correct paths to your dSYMs:

```
mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == UUID"
```

You can use the below post as a reference:

[Firebase Crashlytics DSYM file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61068511/firebase-crashlytics-dsym-file/61083389#61083389).

Comment: Thanks! Is this command similar to those 2 which are specified by firebase on a screenshot?

Comment: That screenshot references how you can manually upload optional missing dSYM's using the upload script, if the Crashlytics runscript provided isn't working for whatever reason. There's a little more information on this here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=ios#upload-dsyms

Comment: ${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}/Contents/Resources/DWARF/${TARGET_NAME}.
how to and where i have to use this comman, i am unable to understand. please help @OlegKodysh

Comment: @HimaniSharma, that path is for the "Input files" field under "Run script" in Xcode, in the Build Phases section. It points to where Xcode generates your dSYMs so that the run script can automatically send them over to Firebase to symbolicate your crash reports.

Comment: Hello @Jake Cronin, I have used Package manager for firebase crashanalytics but dSYM file is not upload