# React Native with Firebase crashlytics

Tags: firebase, react-native, crashlytics

I'm trying to setup crashlytics with my React Native app. When I manually crash the app using

```
crashlytics().crash()
```

I can see the error was sent to Firebase but says it needs dSYM uploaded. This is where I got confused.

Some [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62075269/firebase-crashlytics-upload-dsym-automatically) say this can be setup in XCode to have DSYM uploaded automatically, but others mentioned I need to download DSYM from Apple connect and manually upload it to Firebase.

Which is correct?

I tried to setup XCode following the instructions but it didn't work. I want to prevent having to download from App Store Connect since that will mean I'm not able to test it locally.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820171/how-to-get-the-dsym-file-from-the-ipa-file-available-on-app-store